# How to get custom label field from eBay API?

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am having trouble with custom lable field from ebay API. I can get all values escept custom field.
This is my code:

```
$s_endpoint = 'http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping'; 
$apicall = $f_endpoint
            ."?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsIneBayStores"
            ."&SERVICE-VERSION=".$f_version
            . "&SECURITY-APPNAME=".$appID
            . "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML"
            . "&REST-PAYLOAD"
            . "&storeName=".$sellerID
            . "&outputSelector=StoreInfo";
```

This is custom lable field.
[image]

Could you give me the advise to resolve this problem.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorant answer. I assumed you were using the GetItem call. In the GetItem call the custom label field is returned as SKU if you would like to take that route

Answer (score 0):

In the eBay API the *Custom Label* is known as the *SKU*. Sadly this information is not available via the [findItemsIneBayStores](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsIneBayStores.html) operation or any of the others in the *Finding API*. In order to obtain the SKU you are going to have to use the *Shopping API* in conjunction with the *Finding*. The process will be.

1. Use *findItemsIneBayStores* to get the item(s) that you are interested in.
2. Store the value of the [itemId](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsIneBayStores.html#Response.searchResult.item.itemId) field returned in the response. This is the unique item number that eBay assigns to each listing.
3. Call either the [GetSingleItem](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html) or [GetMultipleItems](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html) operation in the *Shopping API*. You pass the *itemId* from Step 2 into the [ItemID](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Request.ItemID) field of the request. **Note the difference in spelling!** You must also ensure that the [IncludeSelector](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Request.IncludeSelector) fields in your request contains the value *Details* otherwise the SKU will not be returned!
4. The *Custom Label* will be returned in the [SKU](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Response.Item.SKU) field in the response.

In addition, once you have the *itemId* you can also call [GetItem](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html) in the *Trading API* to obtain the SKU.